# twitter-bootstrap multiple input group to display the full width of the div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

With twitter bootstrap, I can get a button to appear the full width of the div by adding the `btn-block` or `form-control` classes onto it, like in the example of the first text box below:

[image]

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="asdf">
```

However, when using the [Multiple Button input group](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons-multiple), I cannot figure out how to get the width of the text box to equal the full width of its container div minus the width of the other 2 "C" and "M" buttons.

Here is the code that I'm using for this second "C/M/textbox" input:

```
<div class="input-group input-group-sm">
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="">C</span></button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="">M</span></button>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
```

Comment: There is most likely another element limiting your input-group because by default it should be full-width. If I use the code you posted by itself, it's full-width.

Comment: @vanburenx okay thanks - I'll check it out!

Comment: Yeah - I must have edited something in the main css file ages ago and not remembered.  I'll close the question.

Comment: Definitely happens and sounds good.